# Why were the ox and the goat intertwined before taking them out to be burnt?

Tags: yom-kippur, korban, fire-burning, kohen-gadol

Why did the Kohen Godol intertwine the ox and the goat before taking them out to be burnt as it says in the [Mishnah Yoma 6 (7)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.6.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

> בָּא לוֹ אֵצֶל פָּר וְשָׂעִיר הַנִּשְׂרָפִין. קְרָעָן וְהוֹצִיא אֶת
>   אֵמוּרֵיהֶן, נְתָנָן בְּמָגֵיס, וְהִקְטִירָן עַל גַּבֵּי הַמִּזְבֵּחַ.
>   **קְלָעָן בְּמִקְלָעוֹת** וְהוֹצִיאָן לְבֵית הַשְּׂרֵפָה

Answer (score 1):

According to the Art Scroll Gemora Yoma 67b3 note 41, the limbs were intertwined so that they could be put on two poles and carried by four people walking two abreast. Thus they were carried together to the place of burning. The two animals were the chatas offerings that had been brought, so they were supposed to be burnt together. As a result, they were carried on the same poles.

> <sup>41</sup> He intertwined the limbs of the slaughtered bull with
>   those of the slaughtered he goat. The two animals where then strung
>   onto two polesm carried by four people walking abreast. At this point
>   the animals were still whole except where the *emurim* had been
>   removed (*Rashi*; cf. *Rambam*, cited below note 47; *Meiri*)
>
> [As noted in the marginal gloss, the Moshnah text as it appears in
>   *Yerushalmi* reads: He intertwined [the limbs of the bull and the he goat] *onto poles* (במַקלוֹת) rather than *into braids* (במַקלָעוֹת).
>   See also *Rabbeinu Elyakim; Dikdukei Soferim*; see also below note 46]
>
> <sup>47</sup> *Rambam (Hil. Avodas Yom Hkippurim 3:7)*, however,
>   maintains that the bull and the he goat were partially dismembered
>   *before* being sent out of the Temple, with the pieces still somewhat attached and *braided* together.

Comment: I sort of feel they could have been carried out on the poles without being intertwined. I wonder whether there was another purpose in the intertwining (eg not to have visible the cut where the emurim were removed).